# Unexpected token error for apparent valid assignment?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, apex-email-service, compile-error, inboundservices

What is wrong with this test class?

I'm getting the error:

> Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token '='. at line 7 column 19

This is at "email.subject = ..."

What is possibly wrong with this assignment? It's exactly as described in Salesforce coding guidelines.

```
@IsTest
public class NewRelicInboundEmailAlerts_Test {

Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

email.subject = 'FW: Incident 20216330';
env.fromAddress = 'exampleemail@domain.com';

// add an Binary attachment
Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment attachment = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment();
attachment.body = blob.valueOf('test');
attachment.fileName = 'bd27b20b74e689b19eacd89ed7a2a62decba7356.json';
attachment.mimeTypeSubType = 'application/json';

email.binaryAttachments = new Messaging.inboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] { attachment };

// call the email service class and test it with the data in the testMethod
NewRelicInboundEmailAlerts testEmailAlert = new NewRelicInboundEmailAlerts();
testEmailAlert.handleInboundEmail(email, env);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't directly use them in class. This is not the correct format.

You need methods to assign them value.

```
public static testmethod testOne() {
  Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
  Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

  email.subject = 'FW: Incident 20216330';
  env.fromAddress = 'exampleemail@domain.com';

  // add an Binary attachment
  Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment attachment = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment();
  attachment.body = blob.valueOf('test');
  attachment.fileName = 'bd27b20b74e689b19eacd89ed7a2a62decba7356.json';
  attachment.mimeTypeSubType = 'application/json';

  email.binaryAttachments = new Messaging.inboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] { attachment };

  // call the email service class and test it with the data in the testMethod
  NewRelicInboundEmailAlerts testEmailAlert = new NewRelicInboundEmailAlerts();
  testEmailAlert.handleInboundEmail(email, env);

}
```

Comment: Absolutely, quite literally just figured this out looking at someone else's answer. It's confusing as they said using testMethod is deprecated now in guidelines?

Anyway - thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: @MattGarnett Yes, testMethod should not be used.

Comment: @sfdcfox Hi fox, so what's the alternative here out of interest?

Comment: @MattGarnett `@isTest` should be used both to identify test classes and methods. See [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm):  "The testMethod keyword is now deprecated. Use the \@isTest annotation on classes and methods instead."